# How do I show logs in the console using angular-CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using angular-cli for webpack.

> ng serve

and the build succeed and I see

> ** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200. **
>   Hash: dd30d5aeee6e21802b4d                                                    e Time: 9397ms
>   chunk    {0} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.map (styles) 163 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
>   chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.map (main) 6.52 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
>   chunk    {2} scripts.bundle.js, scripts.bundle.map (scripts) 361 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
>   chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.map (vendor) 2.22 MB [initial] [rendered]
>   chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]
>   webpack: bundle is now VALID.

nothing seems to be wrong. But I don't see any logs on the console when I access  http://localhost:4200. Is there anyway I could turn on the server log on console?

Comment: Is there something in particular you console.log in your app.component.ts that ain't showing.. console.log ("Hello world").

Comment: lol oh my goodness the fact I had to google this upsets me

Answer (score 15):

Although you can't log dom/web events in the console that don't cause server requests, you can increase the amount of information that the compilation process and static web server provide by passing a `--verbose` flag when starting up: `ng serve --verbose`.

Also, if you're running a proxy a server to hit a local API server and you want some more logging regarding how those requests are being proxied, you can increase the `logLevel` in your proxy configuration.

Example `proxy.conf.json`:

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3001",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

You would then be starting the server as `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --verbose`.

Comment: When I added the `--verbose` flag, I got `Unknown option: '--verbose'`.

Comment: @Jacob according to [Documentation](https://angular.io/cli/serve) we can only toggle --verbose true/false, can you point the source of available logLevel ?

Answer (score 8):

You can't make your angular code log to the shell that started `ng serve`, sorry :-(

You will only see build errors in that console

Answer (score 1):

When I do **console.log("something")** the log is appearing in the browser inspector console tab. I do not need any configuration.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! However, what I meant was that I want to see the server log. I expected seeing logs from server requests on my local console. Is that possible on angular-cli?

Comment: Well, In the client side, Have in mind that angular ts is converted into js files and they run on the client and not in the server, so that, looks weird to try to log in the server something is running in the client.

Comment: how can i see logs i terminal 
? like if i am tesing on tab/mobile then how will i be able to see the error logs ?

Comment: @TMEE Why this answer has negative votes? It makes sense. Remember that your app is supposed to run in a browser. So console.log outputs will be available in your browser console. You could transpile typescript without angular CLI, then you would serve your app as static files in a web server. Unless you are using angular CLI as a deploy server on production, but that would be nonsense

Comment: the app is being SERVED by a web server when it's launched with 'ng serve'  the question is how to see the (request and other) logs generated by that server.  It's a reasonable request.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the filter in console window of your google chrome browser, then you can see the message which you have written in  console.log() method.
[image]

Comment: This answer is wrong. The question was if we can see logs on the development server to check if any clinet is connected to the server. This is not about seeing logs in clients browser console.

Comment: @JyotiPrasadPal It is not wrong to me. It makes sense. Remember that your app is supposed to run in a browser. So console.log outputs will be available in your browser console. You could transpile typescript without angular CLI, then you would serve your app as static files in a web server. Unless you are using angular CLI as a deploy server on production, but that would be nonsense

Answer (score 1):

you can also install and run another server.  a simple one to use can be installed via npm:

```
npm install http-server
```

if you're using routing, you might want to use spa-http-server

```
npm install spa-http-server
```

Comment: my only problem with this answer, which could be the best answer is you need to finish out the explanation i.e. how to change the script and how to run it on a new server.

Comment: he's looking for an alternative to ng serve, which is a development environment only tool, so instructions for building an actual web server are way outside of the scope of the question.  I didn't mention the need to run ng build and needing to serve the contents of the /dist folder either, but all of that is very well covered by the angular cli documentation.  Running an alternate server is an option to get more verbose logging by default than the simple server provided by ng cli.