# How to see angular logs in Terminal?

Tags: angular

I have started my **Angular** application by using `npm start` command.

`console.log()` prints the logs in browser only.

How to see logs in **terminal window**?

Comment: Angular is generally used as a client-side framework, so it will print `console.log` why you want to see logs on terminal side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41056964/how-do-i-show-logs-in-the-console-using-angular-cli)

Comment: want to know the service hit counts

Answer (score 0):

This is, unfortunately, not possible if you're talking about purely taking those logs out of the dev tools and putting them into a terminal window instead.

`console.log`, `console.warn`, and `console.error` are all things that are logged to the browser after the project has been served and rendered for a client-side language such as Angular.

Therefore anything that is logged is then sent to the browser's console.

The errors you will see appear in the terminal window you are using are likely build errors that come up when you attempt to serve up/rebuild your application.

The only way I can think of doing what you're asking is if you have unit tests on set functions that have `console.log` present in them. When you run the unit tests it will print out the `console.log` statement you've created based on the variables you have provided the unit test with.